# keep the setInterval function time in a config file in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, setinterval

I have a js function

```
setInterval(function(){
        $.post( "../../something/", function( data ) {
            $( "#my_id" ).html( data );
        });
    },3000)
```

I have to keep the time `3000` in a `config` file so that it can be changed in the config file itself instead of changing in js file.

Is there a way to do this in yii2?

Comment: Have you considered using the localStorage API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `Yii::$app->params['defaultTimeoutInterval'];` in the HTML, assuming Yii generates the html dynamically, if not, then I'd recommend setting a JS variable in the file that PHP generates that lists out the JS/CSS. Example: `var defaultTimeoutInterval = ${Yii::$app->params['defaultTimeoutInterval']}`

You can change `defaultTimeoutInterval` to whatever suites your needs best, that was just an example.

Assuming you setup `config/params-local.php` to look like:

```
return [
    ...
    'params' => [
        'defaultTimeoutInterval' => 3000,
        ... Additional params
    ]
];
```

Comment: Very well explained teeto, +1 :)

Comment: Can I define `var defaultTimeoutInterval = ${Yii::$app->params['defaultTimeoutInterval']}` in js file? It shows error.

Comment: Could you explain it please? @Yupik

Comment: Could you explain it please? @Brian

Comment: @PaheerathanSelvarasa if you provided more details about how you've setup yii to render the webpage and the javascript, I could provide more meaningful information.